# Azure Http connection gets interrupted after 5 minutes

Tags: azure

We have a setup with several RESTful APIs on the same VM in Azure.
The websites run in Kestrel on IIS.
They are protected by the azure application gateway with firewall.

We now have requests that would run for at least 20 minutes.
The request run the full length uninterrupted on Kestrel (Visible in the logs) but the sender either get "socket hang up" after exactly 5 minutes or run forever even if the request finished in kestrel. The request continue in Kestrel even if the connection was interrupted for the sender.

What I have done:

- Wrote a small example application that returns after a set amount of
  seconds to exclude our websites being the problem.
- Ran the request in the VM (to localhost): No problems, response was received.
- Ran the request within Azure from one to another VM: Request ran forever.
- Ran the request from outside of Azure: Request terminates after 5 minutes
  with "socket hang up".
- Checked set timeouts: Kestrel: 50m , IIS: 4000s, ApplicationGateway-HttpSettings: 3600

Request were tested with Postman,

Is there another request or connection timeout hidden somewhere in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

> We now have requests that would run for at least 20 minutes.

This is a horrible architecture and it should be rewritten to be async. Don't take this personally, it is what it is. Consider returning a `202 Accepted` with a `Location` header to poll for the result.

You're most probably hitting the Azure SNAT layer timeout —

[image: public IP timeout setting]

Change it under the **Configuration** blade for the **Public IP**.

Comment: Thanks you for the idea. It is correct that the timeout on the PublicIP was set to 4m. but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Is that the App Gateway Public IP?

Comment: Yes the VM PublicIds were already set to max. Only the App Gateway Public Id had the default value. It has been set to the max value but the problem persists.

Comment: Same deal if you make the request over the VM's Public IP? The App Gateway could have a TCP timeout in addition to that HTTP one, not sure, check its ARM definition under https://resources.azure.com.

Comment: We gave up and are refactoring that endpoint to make it async. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into something like this a little while back:

For us the issue was probably the timeout like the other answer suggests but the solution was (instead of increasing timeout) to add PGbouncer in front of our postgres database to manage the connections and make sure a new one is started before the timeout fires.

Not sure what your backend connection looks like but something similar (backend db proxy) could work to give you more ability to tune connection / reconnection on your side.

For us we were running AKS (azure Kubernetes service) but all azure public ips obey the same rules that cause issues similar to this one.

While it isn't an answer I know there are also two types of public IP addresses, one of them is considered 'basic' and doesn't have the same configurability, could be something related to the difference between basic and standard public ips / load balancers?